# C++ : Implementation of an algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, set, geometry

I'm trying to implement the following algorithm :

1. Create a set Sp with a single point P.
2. Compute the distance between every point in Sp and every point outside of it, then add the point with the smallest max distance to Sp.
3. Repeat 2. until Sp has k points.
4. Repeat 1-3 using each point once as the initial P.
5. Take the Sp which has the smallest max distance.

Following is my code :

```
using namespace std;
typedef pair<double,double> pairs ;
#define x first
#define y second    
#define INF numeric_limits<double>::infinity();

double dist(double x1,double y1,double x2,double y2)
{
    return pow(((x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2)),1/2);
}


int main()
{
    int n,k;      // n = total points, k= min points to be included

    pairs a[n];
    int vis[n]={0};

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    cin>>a[i].x>>a[i].y;

    set< pairs > s;
    double ans=INF;
    double least=INF;

    int id=0;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        s.clear();
        memset(vis,0,sizeof(vis));

        while(s.size()<=k)          // till set has k points
        {
            s.insert(a[i]);
            vis[i]=1;

            for(auto v:s) // every point in set
            {
                for(int j=0;j<n;j++)  // point outside 
                {
                   if(!vis[j])    
                    {
                        double d = dist(v.x,v.y,a[j].x,a[j].y);
                        if(d<=ans)           // compare and find least
                        {
                            ans=d;
                            id=j;
                        }
                    }

                }
               s.insert(a[id]);                // add least dist point
               if(s.size()>=k)
               break;
            }

        }


        least=min(least,ans);
        cout<<"least="<<least<<"\n";

    }
```

But the code is stuck at point where it needs to insert the min point in the set.It's not inserting the point with smallest max distance to Sp. I don't know if there are any other mistakes in implementation.

Can someone please check out this implementation and help in correcting the mistakes ?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, ans is set to -1 by default. And this will never happen if I am not wrong:

> ```
>                     if(d<=ans)           // compare and find least
>                     {
>                         ans=d;
>                         id=j;
>                     }
> ```
>
> You just insert a[0] repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone please check out this implementation and help in correcting the mistakes ?

Without a set of example points, it's difficult to really test your code but...

(1) the following part it's extremely dangerous

```
int n,k;      // n = total points, k= min points to be included

pairs a[n];
int vis[n]={0};

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
cin>>a[i].x>>a[i].y;
```

I hope that in your real code there is something as

```
static constexpr int n = <a n value>;
static constexpr int k = <a k value>;
```

or at least, with evils macros,

```
#DEFINE n <a n value>
#DEFINE k <a k value>
```

because, if you define a couple of C-style arrays with dimensions set runtime in a couple of variables

```
pairs a[n];
int vis[n]={0};
```

your code isn't C++ standard.

Moreover, if your variables aren't set (as in you example code), the behaviour is undefined (a.k.a. crash in funny ways).

If your dimension (`k` and `n`) are set runtime (from standard input?) you should use a couple of `std::vector`s instead of C-style arrays; something like (caution: code not tested)

```
int n;  // total points
int k;  // min points to be included

std::cin >> n;  // read n from standard input
std::cin >> k;  // read k from standard input

std::vector<pairs>  a   { n };
std::vector<int>    vis { n, 0 };

for ( int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i )
   std::cin >> a[i].x >> a[i].y;
```

(2) if you want to exit from the cycle with `k` points

```
while(s.size()<=k)          // till set has k points
```

your test for `while` has to be `s.size() < k`, not `s.size() <= k`.

Otherwise you remain in the cycle when `size()` is `k`, you add another point and exit with `k+1` points

(3) If you want repeatedly to add the point with minimal distance from set, the following code

```
   while(s.size()<=k)          // till set has k points
    {
        s.insert(a[i]);
        vis[i]=1;

        for(auto v:s) // every point in set
        {
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)  // point outside 
            {
               if(!vis[j])    
                {
                    double d = dist(v.x,v.y,a[j].x,a[j].y);
                    if(d<=ans)           // compare and find least
                    {
                        ans=d;
                        id=j;
                    }
                }

            }
           s.insert(a[id]);                // add least dist point
           if(s.size()>=k)
           break;
        }
```

is wrong because

(3a) you don't initialize `ans` to INF (you have to initialize it before the cycle for every point insertion, not only one time in the program)

(3b) you have to insert the point outside the `for (auto v : s)` loop, not inside

(3c) you have to set `v[id] = 1` when you insert `a[id]` in `s`, or the following cycle you insert again the same `id`

(3d) you should insert `a[i]` only one time, outside the `while()` cycle, not inside, again and again, at every iteration

(3e) not an error but... your cycle `for(auto v:s)` doesn't modify `v` so, to avoid unnecessaries copies, why don't `for ( auto const & v : s )`?

(3f) there is no need of `if(s.size()>=k) break;`

Remembering point (2), i suppose you could write something like

```
   s.insert(a[i]);

   vis[i] = 1;

   while ( s.size() < k ) // till set has k points
    {
      ans = INF;

      for ( auto const & v : s ) // every point in set
       {
         for ( int j = 0 ; j < n ; ++j )  // point outside 
          {
            if ( ! vis[j] )    
             {
               double d { dist(v.x, v.y, a[j].x, a[j].y) };

               if (d <= ans ) // compare and find least
                {
                  ans = d;
                  id  = j;
                }
             }
          }
       }

      s.insert(a[id]); // add least dist point

      v[id] = 1;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, the code is working is working as expected till the *4*th point of algorithm. For the last step of algorithm, how should I have the that set Sp ? Can you help me with this ?